# Unhandled rejection error: invalid config key requested when attempting to update Cypress via NPM

Tags: npm, key, installation, config, cypress

I am trying to update Cypress to the latest version using the following provided command:

```
npm install --save-dev cypress@3.2.0
```

In previous versions this has worked fine with no errors. Now, when I run this, I keep getting the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: invalid config key requested: agentn 099cbf610e4ce787
    at BadKeyError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/figgy-pudding/index.js:93:23)
    at pudGet (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/figgy-pudding/index.js:101:5)
    at FiggyPudding.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/figgy-pudding/index.js:27:12)
    at Object.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/figgy-pudding/index.js:159:16)
    at new PacoteOptions (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/util/opt-check.js:9:21)
    at optCheck (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/util/opt-check.js:63:10)
    at Object.manifest (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/manifest.js:11:10)
    at fetchPackageMetadata (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:58:10)
    at limited (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/call-limit/call-limit.js:29:10)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:235:14
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:52:35
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:52:11
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at asyncMap (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:51:8)
    at exports.getAllMetadata (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:206:3)

npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/jaswindersingh/.npm/_logs/2019-03-15T13_32_13_190Z-debug.log
```

Could anyone point me to what this means and how I can fix it? 
Never seen this kind of error before?

And as far as I know I've not made any changes to any of my packages in either `package.json` or `package-lock.json` etc (from what I have read so far from similar posts)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an `npm` issue.

Try to delete `package-lock.json` and run your command again. This should solve your problem.

Also, if you can, try to upgrade your `npm` version, since this issue is marked as closed in `npm` repository.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, I did remove the `package-lock.json` file and it still responds with the same error.
I can't even upgrade to a newer version of NPM because it shows me the following
`npm ERR! code EBADKEY`
`npm ERR! invalid config key requested: agent`

Answer (score 0):

It is really npm issue. Try to change version to some up-to-date one. If there is some problems with it, you can use nvm.

In my case I`ve changed node version 10.8.0 to 12.18.3 and npm as well.